# php output json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to make it easy for me to request json output using jquery from php/mysql.  Right now I'm using the below.  Can anyone recommend a better way??

/do.php?username=bob

```
<?php
    $str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if($str != ''){
        if(preg_match("/username/",$str)){
            parse_str($str);
            $json = json_encode(checkUserName($username));
            echo $json;
        }
    }
    function checkUserName($v){
        $db = new DB();
        $db->connectDB();

        $findUsername = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '$v'");
        $countUser = mysql_fetch_row($findUsername);
        if($countUser[0] < 1){
            return array('username' => 'false');
        }else{
            return array('username' => 'true');
        }

        $db->disconnectDB();
    }
?>
```

I get back a clean {'username':'false'} or {'username':'true'} which works for what I need; but is there a better way in PHP to do this?

Wow - amazing answers! I dumped my old db class and replaced it with:

```
<?php
  function db_connect(){
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thisdb", "dbuser", "dbpass");
    return ($dbh);
  }
?>
```

Then in my do.php script I made this change:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['username'])){
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode(checkUserName($_GET['username']));
  }

  function checkUserName($v){
    $dbh = db_connect();
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '%s'", addslashes($v));
    if($count = $dbh->query($sql)){
      if($count->fetchColumn() > 0){
        return array('username'=>true);
      }else{
        return array('username'=>false);
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

and my jquery is:

```
function checkUserName(str){
  $.getJSON('actions/do.php?username=' + str, function(data){
    var json = data;
    if(json.username == true){
      // allowed to save username
    }else{
      // not allowed to save username
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `$db->disconnectDB();` is unreachable.

Comment: Where is the `DB` class?

Comment: Please fix the SQL injection vulnerability - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php (and preferably switch to using mysqli_* or pdo instead of the obsolete mysql_* functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
if($str != ''){
    if(preg_match("/username/",$str)){
        parse_str($str);
        $json = json_encode(checkUserName($username));
        echo $json;
    }
}
```

This can be written so much easier by using `$_GET` superglobal:

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    echo json_encode(checkUserName($_GET['username']));
}
```

Inside `checkUserName()`:

```
$findUsername = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '$v'");
```

You should escape `$v` properly:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($v));
$findUsername = mysql_query($sql);
```

Better yet, learn PDO / mysqli and use prepared statements.

```
$db->disconnectDB();
```

Unless you're using persistent connections, you don't need this statements. If you do, you should keep the return value inside a variable first and only return after the disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your DB class, but this looks prettier.

```
<?php

function checkUserName($v){
    $db = new DB();
    $db->connectDB();

    $findUsername = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = '$v'");
    $countUser = mysql_fetch_row($findUsername);
    $db->disconnectDB(); // no code after "return" will do effect

    return ($countUser[0] != 0); // returning a BOOL true is better than a string "true"
}

// use addslashes to prevent sql injection, and use isset to handle $_GET variables.
$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? addslashes($_GET['username']) : '';

// the above line is equal to:
//  if(isset($_GET['username'])){
//      $username = addslashes($_GET['username']);
//  }else{
//      $username = '';
//  }

echo json_encode(checkUserName($username));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fix just replace your checkUsername function with this one:

```
function checkUserName($v){
  $db = new DB();
  $db->connectDB();  

  $findUsername = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$v' LIMIT 1");

  if(mysql_num_rows($findUsername))
    return array('username' => mysql_result($findUsername,0));
  else
    return array('username' => 'false');

}
```

Or a simplier way:

```
if(isset($_GET['username'])){

     $db = new DB();
     $db->connectDB();

     $query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT username FROM user 
                            WHERE username='%s'",
                            mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username'])
                         );

     if(mysql_num_rows($query))
        $json = array('username'=>mysql_result($query,0));
     else
        $json = array('username'=>false);

     header('content-type:application/json');
     echo json_encode($json);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By your way, If you want to process the json data in `jquery` you can do like this

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:'username=bob',
            url: "do.php",
            success: function(jsonData){
                var jsonArray = eval('(' + jsonData + ')');

                if(jsonArray.username == 'true'){
                    // some action here
                }else if((jsonArray.username == 'false')){
                    // someother action hera
                }



            }
        },"json");
```

Comment: I have the jquery down using $.getJSON()